# You attempted an operation on a VM which lacks the feature. (Xenserver)

Tags: xenserver

**Hello all,**

**I'm trying to assign a static IP to a CentOS VM through XenServer (7.6) CLI !**

For [windows](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX214778?_ga=2.226092570.1005600485.1572842129-1389436636.1571652295) vm it is possible !!

**I followed the below steps,**

> 1) xe vm-vif-list vm=(VM-name-label)
>
> 2) xe vif-list vm-uuid=(uuid-of-the-VM)
>
> 3) xe vif-configure-ipv4 uuid=(UUID-of- VIF) mode=static
>   address=w.x.y.z/24 gateway=a.b.c.d

When I use the above steps I got some error, Please find the error below,

**Error Message**

**"You attempted an operation on a VM which lacks the feature."**
[Screenshot of the error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWe2w.png)

> Can anyone please help me to solve this? Kindly let me know if I miss
>   anything ??

Thanks in advance,

Antonynixson I

Comment: Have you installed XenServer Tools inside VM?

Comment: Hello batistuta09, Thanks for the replay,  Yes i have installed Xenserver tools inside the VM

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late 
but it seems from the screenshot that the gateway is not reachable by the ip subnet mask

and it seems xenserver treat any error with the same message